# how to build the mix IDE

Tags: installation, mix, compilation

anyone knows how to build the mix IDE? I found no info on this in the README or elsewhere.
When I try to build master via cmake I am getting:

```
 ➜  3rd cmake mix          
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    EthDependencies


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    EthExecutableHelper


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    EthCompilerSettings


SRC_LIST: ./src/QFunctionDefinition.cpp;./src/QContractDefinition.cpp;./src/Exceptions.cpp;./src/MixApplication.cpp;./src/QVariableDeclaration.cpp;./src/ClientModel.cpp;./src/QEther.cpp;./src/InverseMouseArea.cpp;./src/QVariableDefinition.cpp;./src/HttpServer.cpp;./src/main.cpp;./src/DebuggingStateWrapper.cpp;./src/FileIo.cpp;./src/QBigInt.cpp;./src/CodeModel.cpp;./src/MixClient.cpp;./src/QBasicNodeDefinition.cpp;./src/Clipboard.cpp;./src/SortFilterProxyModel.cpp;./src/CodeHighlighter.cpp;./src/Web3Server.cpp;./src/ContractCallDataEncoder.cpp
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:50 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindEth.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eth", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eth" with any of
  the following names:

    EthConfig.cmake
    eth-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eth" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Eth_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eth" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:51 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5WebEngine.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5WebEngine", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5WebEngine" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WebEngineConfig.cmake
    qt5webengine-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5WebEngine" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5WebEngine_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5WebEngine" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:59 (qt5_add_resources):
  Unknown CMake command "qt5_add_resources".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ligi/git/3rd/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

when building develop:

```
➜  3rd cmake mix
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    EthPolicy


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (eth_policy):
  Unknown CMake command "eth_policy".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ligi/git/3rd/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: In general you have to compile the whole [webthree-umbrella](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/). the single dependencies dont compile on it own (yet), what system are you on? [Ubuntu](https://ethereum-homestead.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/linux.html)?

Comment: yes ubuntu - but 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the build process does not allow to build subsets of the webthree umbrella. To compile `mix` you will have to compile the whole set:

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/
cd webthree-umbrella/
mkdir build/
cd build/
cmake ..
make -j $(nproc)
```

The mix binary will be available in `build/mix/mix`.

Comment: thanks but it fails for me with: 
CMake Error at libethereum/evmjit/CMakeLists.txt:29 (llvm_map_components_to_libnames):
  Unknown CMake command "llvm_map_components_to_libnames".

Answer (score 3):

You're missing some dependencies, at least the qt libraries, see below. Mix can't be build on its own, you need more building blocks before.

This image depicts quite well the Mix dependencies :

[image: dependencies]

Like you, I tried at first to just compile mix and it's in fact simpler to compile the whole cpp stuff, Mix will be in it.
The [instructions](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/linux.html) are located here.
It boils down to :

- install the dependencies with your package manager (`sudo apt-get install` or `sudo aptitude install`), on Ubuntu these are :

`build-essential git cmake libboost-all-dev libgmp-dev libleveldb-dev libminiupnpc-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libcryptopp-dev libmicrohttpd-dev libjsoncpp-dev libargtable2-dev libedit-dev mesa-common-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 opencl-headers libgoogle-perftools-dev qtbase5-dev qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libqt5webengine5-dev ocl-icd-dev libv8-dev libz-dev libjsonrpccpp-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtwebengine`

- if you're not on Ubuntu you may have troubles with *libqt5webengine5-dev* and *libcryptopp-dev* which depending on the distro aren't shipped exactly the way the compiler want. I may add something on that if you need, I successfully compiled everything on Debian which lacks both libraries.

So on Debian you're not getting libqt5webengine5-dev. The way I got around those 2 dependencies issues was the following :

1. download Qt 5.4 (the version is important ) on the [website](http://www.qt.io/download/) , they ask you a few questions. Personally i installed it in my home directory (/home/YOURUSER)
2. Now you'll have to tell cmake how to find that library : I used `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/YOURUSER/Qt/5.4/gcc_64`

Accordingly, if you're not getting the correct version of libcrytopp you'll need to compile it yourself.

1. `wget http://cryptopp.com/cryptopp562.zip`
2. `unzip cryptopp562.zip -d cryptopp`
3. if `make libcryptopp.a libcryptopp.so cryptest.exe` in cryptopp directory fails, you may need to edit GNUmakefile and uncomment `CXXFLAGS += -fPIC`
4. `sudo make install`

   - Clone the repo, recursively :) and checkout the release you want :

   `git clone --recursive https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella.git` then `git checkout XXXX`

   - create the build directory, move in it and cmake !
     `mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake ..`

Should your cmake not pass all the test you can comment and I'll try to tell you what's missing :)

Comment: thanks! can you elaborate on libqt5webengine5-dev and libcryptopp-dev - I am getting: E: Unable to locate package libcryptopp-dev
E: Unable to locate package libqt5webengine5-dev
E: Unable to locate package qml-module-qtwebengine

Comment: I edited my answer with specific instructions for Debian related to the missing dependencies, hope it helps. What distro are you using ?

Comment: thanks - still installing this qt beast - this takes ages ;-)

Comment: still facing a problem: https://gist.github.com/ligi/44808751f5c013cd2fe3 - do I have to set all these variables by hand?

Comment: no, you're missing the eth dependencies, look at the graph I put, you can't compile mix alone, it needs Qt (you solved that apparently) and web3jsonrpc which itself needs webthree which needs whisper, etc etc....so you better compile everything

Comment: ligi, try `cmake . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/ligi/bin/qt/5.4/gcc_64` without mix

Comment: compiling everything brought me further but fails with CMake Error at libethereum/evmjit/CMakeLists.txt:29 (llvm_map_components_to_libnames):
  Unknown CMake command "llvm_map_components_to_libnames".

uilding software ( java ) every day - and going through this mud now really lets me appreciate how gradle+maven-central just automates this ugly task of getting dependencies right ..

Comment: you seem to miss llvm-3.7-dev

Comment: @euri10 What did you use to create the diagram?

Comment: I didn't create it, just took it from an old wiki in the old cpp ethereum repo, can't remember where now sorry