# Installing solidity in Debian Linux

Tags: solidity, solc, remix, console, debian

I'm trying to install solidity but apparently there are no online repositories with all dependencies. I have tried using the methods described [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contract-Tutorial).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install solc
which solc
```

The repository is down.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum-dev/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/cmake-3.x/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried compiling the bundle from [here](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/index.html). I am using debian 8.3 jessie and attempted to install the packages for [Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty tar)](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/linux-ubuntu.html) but I had the same repository issue with llvm (see below).

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x

sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install language-pack-en-base
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
sudo apt-get -y install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.7 main"
wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install llvm-3.7-dev

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-qt
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade

sudo apt-get -y install build-essential git cmake libboost-all-dev libgmp-dev \
    libleveldb-dev libminiupnpc-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev libcryptopp-dev libmicrohttpd-dev libjsoncpp-dev \
    libargtable2-dev libedit-dev mesa-common-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 opencl-headers \
    libgoogle-perftools-dev qtbase5-dev qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev \
    libqt5webkit5-dev libqt5webengine5-dev ocl-icd-dev libv8-dev libz-dev

sudo apt-get -y install libjson-rpc-cpp-dev
sudo apt-get -y install qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtwebengine
```

Is there any binary of the **solidity** compiler available?

Or is there a way to invoke the **solidity browser compiler** from the command line?

**Edit:**

The build log file is:

```
$ ./webthree-helpers/scripts/ethbuild.sh --no-git --project solidity --cores 4 -DEVMJIT=0 -DETHASHCL=0 # build Solidity only

ETHBUILD - INFO: Starting build of webthree-helpers/utils for requested project solidity.

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- boost headers: /usr/include
-- boost lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_random.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
-- Found gmp: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so  
-- Gmp headers: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
-- Gmp lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    ETHASHCL
    EVMJIT


-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/log
Scanning dependencies of target secp256k1
Scanning dependencies of target scrypt
[ 10%] [ 20%] [ 30%] [ 40%] Building C object libscrypt/CMakeFiles/scrypt.dir/crypto_scrypt-hash.c.o
Building C object secp256k1/CMakeFiles/secp256k1.dir/secp256k1.c.o
Building C object libscrypt/CMakeFiles/scrypt.dir/crypto_scrypt-check.c.o
Building C object libscrypt/CMakeFiles/scrypt.dir/crypto-mcf.c.o
[ 50%] Building C object libscrypt/CMakeFiles/scrypt.dir/crypto-scrypt-saltgen.c.o
[ 60%] Building C object libscrypt/CMakeFiles/scrypt.dir/b64.c.o
[ 70%] [ 80%] Building C object libscrypt/CMakeFiles/scrypt.dir/sha256.c.o
Building C object libscrypt/CMakeFiles/scrypt.dir/crypto_scrypt-nosse.c.o
[ 90%] Building C object libscrypt/CMakeFiles/scrypt.dir/crypto_scrypt-hexconvert.c.o
[100%] Building C object libscrypt/CMakeFiles/scrypt.dir/slowequals.c.o
Linking C shared library libscrypt.so
[100%] Built target scrypt
Linking C static library libsecp256k1.a
[100%] Built target secp256k1

ETHBUILD - INFO: Starting build of libweb3core for requested project solidity.

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- boost headers: /usr/include
-- boost lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_random.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Configuring dev
------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                  CMake Version                            3.0.2
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Build type                               RelWithDebInfo
-- TARGET_PLATFORM  Target platform                          Linux
--------------------------------------------------------------- features
-- PROFILING        Profiling support                        OFF
-- PARANOID         -                                        OFF
-- MINIUPNPC        -                                        ON
------------------------------------------------------------- components
-- TESTS            Build tests                              ON
-- TOOLS            Build tools                              ON
------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Found jsoncpp: /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so  
-- JsonCpp headers: /usr/include/jsoncpp
-- JsonCpp lib   : /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so
-- Found leveldb: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so  
-- LevelDB headers: /usr/include
-- LevelDB lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so
-- Found CryptoPP: /usr/include (found suitable version "5.6.2", minimum required is "5.6.2") 
-- CryptoPP headers: /usr/include
-- CryptoPP lib   : /usr/lib/libcryptopp.a
-- Found miniupnpc: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libminiupnpc.so  
-- miniupnpc headers: /usr/include
-- miniupnpc lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libminiupnpc.so
./test.cpp./overlaydb.cpp./memorydb.cpp./..//./FixedHash.cpp./..//./Base36.cpp./..//./core.cpp./..//./CommonJS.cpp./..//./RangeMask.cpp./..//./rlp.cpp./..//./SecretStore.cpp./..//./crypto.cpp./..//./trie.cpp./..//./AES.cpp./..//./hexPrefix.cpp./..//./MemTrie.cpp./..//./peer.cpp./..//./eip-8.cpp./..//./rlpx.cpp./..//./capability.cpp./..//./net.cpp
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:21 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    ./.././FixedHash.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/log
ETHBUILD - ERROR: cmake configure phase for repository "libweb3core" failed.
```

**Edit:**

After installing all dependencies and following the build steps:

```
$ cd webthree-umbrella
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user/solidityDependencies/Qt/5.6/gcc_64
```

**cmake** fails with the following errors:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Configuring ethereum
------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                  CMake Version                            3.0.2
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Build type                               RelWithDebInfo
-- TARGET_PLATFORM  Target platform                          Linux
--------------------------------------------------------------- features
--                  Hardware identification support          
--                  HTTP Request support                     
-- VMTRACE          VM execution tracing                     OFF
-- PROFILING        Profiling support                        OFF
-- FATDB            Full database exploring                  ON
-- ROCKSDB          Prefer rocksdb to leveldb                OFF
-- OLYMPIC          Default to the Olympic network           OFF
-- PARANOID         -                                        OFF
------------------------------------------------------------- components
-- GUI              Build GUI components                     ON
-- TESTS            Build tests                              ON
-- ETHASHCL         Build OpenCL components                  ON
-- EVMJIT           Build LLVM-based JIT EVM                 OFF
-- SOLIDITY         Build Solidity                           ON
------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_0
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_0 - not found
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_1_2
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_1_2 - found
-- Found OpenCL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 (found version "1.2") 
-- OpenCL headers: /usr/include
-- OpenCL lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1
-- Cpuid headers: CPUID_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- Cpuid lib   : CPUID_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Found json_rpc_cpp: /usr/local/include (found suitable version "0.6.0", minimum required is "0.4") 
-- json-rpc-cpp headers: /usr/local/include
-- json-rpc-cpp lib   : /usr/local/lib/libjsonrpccpp-common.so;/usr/local/lib/libjsonrpccpp-server.so;/usr/local/lib/libjsonrpccpp-client.so
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so  
-- curl headers: /usr/include
-- curl lib   : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so
CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./createRandomTest.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./fuzzHelper.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./commonjs.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./icap.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./dagger.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./keymanager.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./difficulty.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./Transaction.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./GasPricer.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./State.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./TransactionQueue.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./BlockChainInsert.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./BlockChainTests.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./BlockChain.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./BlockQueue.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./Genesis.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./StateOriginal.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./AccountDiff.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./Block.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./TransactionTests.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./ClientBase.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./crypto.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./vm.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./natspec.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:26 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/test/./..//./boost.cpp"
  cannot be read.


CMake Error at libethereum/test/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_test):
  add_test given test NAME ""RandomTestCreationSuite"/&createRandomTest"
  which already exists in this directory.
```

**Edit:**

Not building the test cases; running **cmake** as follows:

```
$ cd webthree-umbrella
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. -DTESTS=0 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/Qt/5.4/gcc_64
```

produces the following output:

```
/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/libethash/internal.c:244:49: error: array subscript is above array bounds [-Werror=array-bounds]
   reduction = reduction * FNV_PRIME ^ mix->words[w + 1];
                                                 ^
/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/libethash/internal.c:245:49: error: array subscript is above array bounds [-Werror=array-bounds]
   reduction = reduction * FNV_PRIME ^ mix->words[w + 2];
                                                 ^
/home/user/webthree-umbrella/libethereum/libethash/internal.c:246:49: error: array subscript is above array bounds [-Werror=array-bounds]
   reduction = reduction * FNV_PRIME ^ mix->words[w + 3];
                                                 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
libethereum/libethash/CMakeFiles/ethash.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target 'libethereum/libethash/CMakeFiles/ethash.dir/internal.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [libethereum/libethash/CMakeFiles/ethash.dir/internal.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:810: recipe for target 'libethereum/libethash/CMakeFiles/ethash.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [libethereum/libethash/CMakeFiles/ethash.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: compile the whole c++ branch (https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/) that is way simpler than trying to cherry pick what you want

Comment: I only need solidity from the branch and it will fail regardless since the branch contains solidity.

Comment: whenever i tried to compile only parts of that c++ bundle I failed, I know you don't need every single executable in it but nonetheless try to see if it works using the entire bundle, well that's what I ended up doing as i couldn't solve the errors I got trying to cherry-pick what I wanted (Mix in my case, solidity in yours)

Comment: If you want to build all you simply run cmake?

Comment: I would do a `cmake -DGUI=0` in your case to avoid being stuck by the Qt dependencies not handled by Debian, unless you wanna install Qt manually which I explain also in my Mix answer ;)

Comment: I've installed qt. Do you know how may I direct the cmake file of webthree-umbrella to it? The binaries are downloaded into a directory and still need to be placed into the /usr/bin /usr/lib directories.

Comment: try `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/YOURUSER/Qt/5.4/gcc_64` or wherever you installed Qt5.4

Comment: @euri10 Did you also have the problem with building the test cases?

Comment: no, I use `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/MyUSER/Qt/5.4/gcc_64` once in the build folder. I don't think the Debug flag makes a difference, I'm though surprised you have cmake 3.0.2, i'm at 3.5.2, so maybe update that ?

Comment: I'll update cmake and try again (I have to rebuild it since this is the latest on debian).

Comment: I'm on Debian too but testing (you might be on stable if you got 3.0.2), testing has 3.5.2 fwiw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't use the ubuntu repos on debian, because some libs especially the libcrypto++-dev are incompatibles,
you'll have to compile the project yourself, this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1450/54) may help

my [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2220/54) here while it deals with the Mix IDE explains specifically what troubles you might encounter compiling all that c++ branch on Debian and can also be useful

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already built libcrypto on my own. Will edit the question soon

Comment: should you have any question don't hesitate, it took me a while, but I think the 2nd link I posted deals with every major issue you could have

Comment: I've updated the question with my logs. It fails on a test case.

Comment: The file is there. I think the directory path is garbled.

Answer (score 2):

Succeeded!

My manual is here:

https://gist.github.com/drandreaskrueger/912e704cfc86fd757277a5fd9bd372d4

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. It looks like a perfect answer. Do you need help with [markdown formatting](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/editing-help)?

Comment: Perhaps @Sebi (who asked the original question) could identify those parts which help him, to solve his problem. I don't want to cite the whole lot.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar problems on Debian, fought with it for a bit, and then just gave up and installed an Ubuntu virtual machine in VirtualBox.

Works great. (Caveat: I only run a private net so can't comment on how painful it is to sync the blockchain.)

Comment: I encourage you to try [my solution](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6364/2937) - I got it all working, incl. all GUI tools.

Comment: I read somewhere that 'geth --fast' should accelerate syncing.